# Is it possible to check if iOS 9 device has WiFi Assist enabled programmatically?

Tags: ios9

I'm trying to check if the WiFi assist is enabled on a device running iOS 9, and then prompt the user to disable it if necessary.

Comment: What did you tried to check that? Please edit your question with more details. Also, explain your problem, perhaps people can help you with an alternative solution.